# Docker runner on Gitlab CI - Proxy only for specific stage

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

For the stage "deploy" I need a proxy. But stage "test" does not work from the point, on where the Karma test is starting. Is there a way, where I can define: Use proxy settings for stage "Deploy" but not for "test"?

I tried to exclude the IP, Karma is using, from proxy but the Ip is changing every time.

```
variables:
      http_proxy: "$CODE_PROXY"
      https_proxy: "$CODE_PROXY"
      no_proxy: "127.0.0.1,localhost"

stages:
  - test
  - deploy


test:
  stage: test
  image: node:erbium
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run lint
    - npm run lint:sass
    - npm run lint:editorconfig
    - npm run test -- --progress=false --code-coverage
    - npm run e2e -- --host=$(hostname -i)
    - npm run build:prod -- --progress=false
  coverage: '/Statements\s*:\s*(\d+\.?\d+)\%/'
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 3h
    paths:
      - dist/
    reports:
      junit: dist/reports/app-name/test-*.xml
      cobertura: dist/coverage/app-name/cobertura-coverage.xml
  tags:
    - DOCKER

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: python:latest
  script:
  - pip install awscli
  - aws s3 rm s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME --recursive
  - aws s3 cp ./dist/app-name s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/ --recursive
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways

1. Mixin variables

```
.proxy-variables: &proxy-variables
      http_proxy: "$CODE_PROXY"
      https_proxy: "$CODE_PROXY"
      no_proxy: "127.0.0.1,localhost"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: python:latest
  variables:
    - *proxy-variables
  script:
    - pip install awscli
    - aws s3 rm s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME --recursive
    - aws s3 cp ./dist/app-name s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/ --recursive
  only:
    - master
```

2. Extend job template

```
.proxied-job:
  variables:
      http_proxy: "$CODE_PROXY"
      https_proxy: "$CODE_PROXY"
      no_proxy: "127.0.0.1,localhost"

deploy:
  extends: .proxied-job
  stage: deploy
  image: python:latest
  script:
    - pip install awscli
    - aws s3 rm s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME --recursive
    - aws s3 cp ./dist/app-name s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/ --recursive
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have googled like a crawler but did not find anything like this. Your solution is exactly what I searched for.